# Is there a Java/Swing datepicker that can select a range of dates?

Tags: library, java

I've looked through some Java Swing datepicker libraries, but I haven't found one that can select a range (a pair) of dates, like many travel search sites do.  Is there one you've run across, of high enough quality to be production-worthy: stable, well-designed, and attractive?

(Searches also bring up a lot of javascript, so I may be missing something in the noise.)